# Arduino Ethernet - unable to upload stk500_getsync() not in sync: resp=0x01

Tags: arduino

First of all I did a big Research session before asking here but I didn't found a solution to fix my Problem.

I have the Arduino Ethernet chip and I have downloaded the latest Beta from the Arduino SDK (I also tried it with the latest stable, same result)
Now when I try to compile it says the following:

> avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr  3 2014 at 23:12:16
>            Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
>            Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch
>
> ```
>      System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
>
>      Using Port                    : COM8
>      Using Programmer              : arduino
>      Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200 avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]  avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]  avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
> ```
>
> avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude:
>
> stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync()
>
> attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
>
> [...]
>
> avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude:
>
> stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.

Yep, I have selected the rigth board, yep I have selected the rigth comport, nope, there is no cable in Output 1 or 2.

I have also tried it with the eclipse plugin, same resulte (due it's the same SDK)

My OS: Windows 8.1 x64
My Programmer: Diamex-AVR
to the programmers.txt file I added this code:

> diamexavr.name=DIAMEX-AVR
>
> diamexavr.communication=Serial
>
> diamexavr.protocol=stk500v2

Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance,
Spider

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specifically about the Arduino tools rather than general programming issues on the arduino platform, and thus belongs on arduino.stackexchange rather than here.

Comment: Try different computer

Comment: I tried different Computer. And @Chris: Sorry i didnt knew that there is a spin-off site for arduino. Nevermind I solved the Problem by using now an Arduino Uno to Flash. Seems like the diamex avr isn't compatible to the Arduino Ethernet but to the Uno.